# Problems with Match and Index

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get the minimal value of DAY with SUBTOTAL, and then getting its EQUIPMENTS equivalent. However whenever I apply a filter in my table MATCH and INDEX don't update to the new filtered values like SUBTOTAL does. Why is that and how can I make it happen? Hope I explained it well.

**Formulas**

SUBTOTAL COUNT: `=SUBTOTAL(3;Table1[DAY])`

SUBTOTAL MIN: `=SUBTOTAL(5;Table1[DAY])`

MATCH: `=MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5;Table1[DAY]);Table1[DAY];0)`

INDEX: `=INDEX(Table1[EQUIPMENTS];G5)`

Bellow table with filter off:
[image]

And then table with filter on:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to include your formulas.

Comment: Per Microsoft, `SUBTOTAL()`  ignores filtered rows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: 2019. Did any of you replicate the sheet values and it behaved differently? If you could post a print

Comment: It won't behave differently.  The problem is that MATCH does not care if the row is visible or not, it returns the relative position of the first match regardless of the filter.  There are ways around it but it would require array formula.

Comment: 2019 doesn't have array formula? So there's no other way to do it?

Comment: @Felippe M., are you required to use `MATCH()`? Or  can you use other formulas? And, can you use a helper column?

Comment: If you are filtering your table by a single equipment type (eg "EQUIP 2") then the type of equipment which corresponds to the minimum of column `VALUE` is always going to be the one you have filtered on - ie "EQUIP 2".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula for MATCH (an array formula if Excel older than 2021):

```
=MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5;Table1[DAY]);SUBTOTAL(3;INDIRECT("C"&ROW(Table1[DAY])))*Table1[DAY];0)
```

It differs a bit from what you expected, because all filtered-off values are replaced by zeros. However thanks to this you can leave your INDEX formula intact.